# Heat stopped working after fixing non-stop fan issue with HVAC heater/air handler unit

Tags: hvac, heater

I am a home owner with the following issue:

On the first cold day, we turned on the heat and it worked fine, but later we noticed that the fan kept running.

Long story short, I fixed that issue but I'm not totally sure how. However, now the heat doesn't come on anymore.

I've ruled out the following:

- thermostat fan switch in the 'on' position
- Shorted out wires between thermostat and unit
- Faulty thermostat (it worked before the fan issue)

The reason I say I don't know how I fixed it is that I tried multiple things while the breaker was off. When I turned it back on the fan was behaving as it should. (note: I had previously turned the breaker off and on a few times - so that alone didn't have an effect)

Here's what I've done in trying to fix the fan issue

- Looked for - and didn't find - any blinking LEDs anywhere
- removed and checked 5A fuse
- unplugged and re-plugged wires on high limit switch, and tapped it lightly
- Lightly tapped the fan relay switch on the control board
- Pressed the button on the flame rollout switch - I think. It didn't really feel like anything was being switched
- Discovered a 'mystery switch' just hanging out in mid-air. I was going to fiddle with it, but the plastic insulation around the connectors was brittle and fell away.

That last thing is what has me most concerned. It wasn't attached anywhere that I could tell and I don't understand what its function is. It looks to me like another flame rollout switch.

When I closed up the unit I was careful to keep it from touching anything.

In the overview picture, I labeled it 'A' and took a couple closeups of it.

[image: Overview]
[image: Flame rollout]
[image: Lame Rollout - alt view]
[image: High Limit Switch]
[image: Mystery Switch]
[image: Mystery Switch - view 2]
[image: Control Board - A]
[image: Control Board - B(fuse)]
[image: Control Board - C]
[image: Thermostat - wired as it was]

Comment: Those are beautiful pictures. I don't suppose you have a picture of the wiring diagram somewhere, do you?

Comment: No such luck unfortunately. I should however probably emphasize that I am the homeowner and not a professional

Comment: Find the Model number and publish it, so we can help looking for the manual

Comment: While waiting for you to publish the model: Did you replace the battery in the Thermostat? Use multimeter and check for 24 Volt (AC) on the W- terminal on the control board, also check the G-therminal on the control board.

Comment: The model number is MPGA075B3
I did replace the battery in the Thermostat in June, and while I did not check for voltage I am certain that it is getting power because.... drumroll please.... The heat is now working.

However, I again don't know why. The only things that have changed since this morning are that I (again) turned off the breaker and turned it back on, and I crawled back up in the attic to take pictures of the Data sticker on the furnace.

The fact that it is working again doesn't make me feel 100% better since I don't know why it failed to for a few days.

Comment: It can't be as simple as the Fonzie move I did when I put the cover back on.

I guess my question now changes to, What should I look out for going forward and what should the next steps be if the heat fails again?